# Covariance matrix of a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose that $Y$ is a d-dimentional brownian motion under a setting $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P)$ adapted to a filtration ${F_t}$. Then is the covariance matrix of $Y$ always diagonal?

In other words is it possible to define a brownian motion that its components have covariance non zero i.e not independent?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion has independent components?

Comment: I know that one can construct a d-dimensional Brownian motion with independent components. However, I am wondering if it is possible to construct a Brownian vector to satisfy continuity, independent increments and gaussianity but with not necessarily independent components.

Comment: No, that's not possible. A $d$-dimensional Brownian motion has always independent components.